# Why did I get run-time error on PC^2?(replace certain words or characters in some strings)

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alter_words {
    char **words;
};

char *changewords_1 (char *sentence, char *find, char *replace)
{
    // destptr:(i)the same address as dest (ii)get the character from sentence
    char *dest = malloc (strlen(sentence) - strlen(find) + strlen(replace) + 1);
    char *destptr = dest;

    *dest = 0;

    while (*sentence)
    {
        // when the string is equal
        if (!strncmp (sentence, find, strlen(find)))
        {
            strcat (destptr, replace);
            sentence += strlen(find);
            destptr += strlen(replace);
        }
        // when the string is not equal
        else
        {
            *destptr = *sentence;
            destptr++;
            sentence++;
        }
    }
    *destptr = 0;
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    static const char * const delimiter = " \t\n";
    char **strs, *word, **alter_word;
    char **result;
    struct alter_words *awords;
    int i, j, n;
    char buffer[2][1500];
    size_t len;

    // read the number of total strings
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);
    strs = malloc(n * sizeof(*strs));
    awords = malloc(n * sizeof(*awords));
    result = malloc(n * sizeof(*result));

    // read the strings and the word want to be replaced
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        fgets(buffer[0], sizeof buffer[0], stdin);
        fgets(buffer[1], sizeof buffer[1], stdin);

        len = strlen(buffer[0]) + 1;
        strs[i] = malloc(len);
        strcpy(strs[i], buffer[0]);

        awords[i].words = malloc(2 * sizeof(*awords[i].words));

        word = strtok(buffer[1], delimiter);
        for (j = 0; word; ++j) {
            awords[i].words[j] = strdup(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }

        strs[i][strcspn(strs[i], "\n")] = 0;
        result[i] = malloc(1500);
        result[i] = changewords_1 (strs[i], awords[i].words[0], awords[i].words[1]);        
        result[i] = realloc(result[i], sizeof(result[i]) );

    }

    // print out the result and release the memories
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        printf("%s\n", result[i]);
        for ( j = j - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            free(awords[i].words[j]);
        }
        free(result[i]);
        free(awords[i].words);
        free(strs[i]);
    }
    free(awords);
    free(strs);
    return 0;
}
```

### input

`step1`: an integer n on a line by itself representing the number of test cases which is less than 9999.

`step2`: two lines
first line: original string
second line: two words separated by space. The first word is the find string and the second one is the replace-by string.
(Both words will be at most 100 characters long.)

### Question

What kinds of problem in my program may contribute to a run-time error in my program?
Besides, as a beginner, any suggestion to my program is welcomed!

### Example

Input

```
3
I like it
like hate
Today's weather is great
o e
hahahahahahahaha
a o
```

Output

```
I hate it
Teday's weather is great
hohohohohohohoho
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. The most severe is here:

```
    result[i] = malloc(1500);
    result[i] = changewords_1 (strs[i], awords[i].words[0], awords[i].words[1]);        
    result[i] = realloc(result[i], sizeof(result[i]) );
```

First, you allocate memory and then throw it away immediately, because the handle to that memory is overwritten with the result of `changewords_1`, which takes care of memory allocation already.

Then you try to shrink the memory to what is actually needed, but you use `sizeof` on a pointer. The size of a pointer is typically 4 or 8, so this will truncate your string and it will no longer be null-terminated. This is the likely cause of your error.

You need `strlen` here, but take care of retaining the null terminator, so:

```
    result[i] = realloc(result[i], strlen(result[i]) + 1);
```

But you don't need the reallocation, because `changewords_1` already allocates the memory for you:

```
char *dest = malloc (strlen(sentence) - strlen(find) + strlen(replace) + 1);
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug here: You replace all occurrences of `find` with `replace`, but when you allocate memory, you don't know yet how many occurrences there are. The allocation above assumes just one, but if your find and replacement strings have different lengths, this calculation is off.

I suggest to implement two passes: The first pass finds how many occurrences of `` find` there are. Then allocate memory accordingly and do the actual replacing in a second pass.

Another problem is your use of `strcat`, which requires the strings to be null terminated. You set:

```
*dest = 0;
```

at the beginning, which is good, but the string isn't guaranteed to be null-terminated any more. You could try `calloc` instead of `malloc`; it zeroes out your memory.

A better approach could be not to use `strcat`, which always recalculates the string length. I'd use `strstr` to find `find` and then `memcpy` to copy chunks of characters.